# Rails: AND operator in a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My relationship is a `Client` can have many `ClientJobs`.  I want to be able to find clients that perform both `Job a` and `Job b`.  I'm using 3 select boxes so I can pick a maximum of three jobs to select from.  The select boxes are populated from the database.

I know how to test for 1 job with the query below. But I need a way to use an `AND` operator to test that both jobs exist for that client.

```
@clients = Client.includes("client_jobs").where(
  client_jobs: { job_name: params[:job1]})
```

Unfortunately it's easy to do an `IN` operation like below, but I'm thinking the syntax for `AND` should be similar....I hope

```
@lients = Client.includes("client_jobs").where(
  client_jobs: { job_name: [params[:job1], params[:job2]]})
```

EDIT: Posting the sql statement that hits the database from the answer below

```
Core Load (0.6ms) SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients`
CoreStatistic Load (1.9ms)  SELECT `client_jobs`.* FROM `client_jobs`
  WHERE `client_jobs `.`client_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,........)
```

The second query runs through every client_job in the database.  It's never tested against the `params[:job1], params[:job2]` etc. So `@clients` returns `nil` crashing my view template

```
(undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, a better approach then self-joins is to simply join `ClientJobs` and then use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses to filter out only those records that exactly match the given associated records.

```
performed_jobs = %w(job job2 job3)
Client.joins(:client_jobs).
       where(client_jobs: { job_name: performed_jobs }).
       group("clients.id").
       having("count(*) = #{performed_jobs.count}")
```

Let's walk through this query:

- first two clauses join the `ClientJob`s to `Client`s and filter out only those, that have **any of the three** jobs defined (it uses the IN clause)
- next, we `group` these joined records by `Client.id` so that we get the clients back
- finally, the `having` clause ensures we only return those clients that had exactly 3 `ClientJob` records joined in, i.e. **only those that had all the three client jobs defined**.

It is the trick with `HAVING(COUNT(*) = ...)` that turns the `IN` clause (which is essentially an `OR`-ed list of options) into a "must have all these" clause.

Comment: Got this one to work but I have 1 question. Can I keep the `performed_jobs` array from assigning parameters with empty strings? The issue is the array assumes all select boxes have been used. so the size of array is always 3

Comment: Sure, you can always do something like `performed_jobs = <assign params...>.select { |j| j.present? }`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a single SQL query try the following:

```
jobs_with_same_user = ClientJob.select(:user_id).where(job_name: "<job_name1>", user_id: ClientJob.select(:user_id).where(job_name: "<job_name2>"))

@clients = Client.where(id: jobs_with_same_user)
```

Here's what this query is doing:

1. Select the `user_id`s of all Client jobs with [job_name2]
2. Select the `user_id`s of all Client jobs with `user_id` IN result set from (1) AND having [job_name1]
3. Select all users with using (2) as a subquery.

Not many know this but Rails 4+ supports subqueries. Basically this is a self join acting as subquery for the `clients`:

```
SELECT *
FROM clients
WHERE id IN <jobs_with_same_user>
```

Also, I'm not sure if you're referencing the `client_jobs` association in your view, but if you are, add the `includes` statement to avoid an N+1 query:

`@clients = Client.includes(:client_jobs).where(id: jobs_with_same_user)`

**EDIT**

If you prefer, the same result can be achieved with a self-referencing inner join:

```
jobs_with_same_user = ClientJob
       .select("client_jobs.user_id AS user_id")
       .joins("JOIN client_jobs inner_client_jobs ON inner_client_jobs.user_id=client_jobs.user_id")
       .where(client_jobs: { job_name: "<first_job_name1>" }, inner_client_jobs: { job_name: "<job_name2>" })

@clients = Client.where(id: jobs_with_same_user)
```

Comment: Works great, but what if I want to query a third job?  I have trouble chaining a third subquery.  The query that's giving the issue is the first query in your answer. `jobs_with_same_user = ClientJob.select(:user_id).where (job_name: "<job_name1>".......`